# How to animate A pose at fame 1 to a final pose at frame 30 in 4.0?

Tags: animation, rigging

I am new to blender animation and rather new to blender in general.

I am trying to make a simple animation for marvelous designer and need the A pose to slowly transition into a final pose for my clothes to fit correctly.

In the animation window I keyed the A pose and then scrubbed to frame 30, posed the character (rigify rigged) and keyed the new position (rotation, position and scale) all in pose mode.

Note: it leaves grey bones in rest pose behind but mesh deforms accordingly regardless.

When playing back, nothing happened and the final pose was displayed throughout, no movement.

I did research on pose to pose animation but was not able to make anything work.

I did not change anything from the default animation window.

Comment: Did you have the rig selected when you keyed the A pose at frame 1? - In Pose mode, Hit A to select All and then I > Rotation, Position and Scale. You can hide the grey bones by unchecking the metarig in the Outliner.

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried both hitting A and box selecting as well. 

Thank you for the answer to the metarig!

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file in that case. If it's not larger than 30Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help! The answer turned out to be a case of newbie user-error. I had to unhide some very important bones before keying since they don’t actually select and therefore don’t actually key…

Comment: Ah! Glad you solved the problem! It might be worth you adding that as an answer since you solved it yourself.